# How to setup default SimpleBlobDetector params in a header file

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm writing an application that uses the opencv function `SimpleBlobDetector`.  The function is called with a parameter input of datatype `cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params`.

Now instead of having all the values directly in my code I'd like to put them in a header file so I can go back and forth between multiple header files for given situations.  Now it's easy enough for me to create a header file that creates a `Params` data type:

```
#ifndef SIMPLEBLOBPARAMS_HPP_INCLUDED
#define SIMPLEBLOBPARAMS_HPP_INCLUDED

namespace simpleblobconstants
{
    cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
}

#endif // SIMPLEBLOBPARAMS_HPP_INCLUDED
```

But how do I assign default values to all the fundamental data types that make up the `Params` data type?

Comment: Do you need this object it self to be shared?

Comment: No, everything will be constants and read only once.

Comment: You can either wrap it in a class/struct or make a function that return this object and initialize it only once

Comment: Good deal, both those options worked just fine.  Thanks.